# How can I add a dot between two numbers?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex

I'm trying to add a dot between two numbers. It's about article numbers, for now they were like XXXXX or XXXXXX and now should be XXX.XX or XXX.XXX which I can't figure out.

Article numbers are loaded automatically from database since there are a lot of them. Right now, they are 99-87503 or 99-400031, and from now on should be 99.875.03 or 99.400.031.

I've tried with specifying numbers, filters and patterns none of which worked.

Current AngularJs code:

```
<div class="status">
    99.{{Manipulated()}} | 
    <p ng-model="Manipulated"
       class="rwd-info-msg {{Manipulated.cssClass}}">
      {{Manipulated.text}}
    </p>
</div>
```

This 99. is just a prefix that should be at every article number.

I'm pretty new to AngularJS, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi, can you write an example of your input data and expected output

Comment: The `ng-model` directive does not work with `<p>` elements.

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't write this code, it's from a colleague and it's very old. Thanks for the heads up about ng-model not working with <p>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularJS way of doing this is creating a custom [`filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter):

```
app.filter('addDot', function() {
  return function(number) {
    return number.toString().slice(0,3) + number.toString().slice(3);
  };
})
```

and use it in your template like:

```
<div class="article-status">
    99.{{getManipulatedArticle(article).artnr | addDot}} </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The naive thing you could do is

```js
var num = 9876543;
var res = num.toString().replace(/^(\d{3})(.*)/ig, '$1.$2');

console.log(num, '->', res);
```

Here, the `(\d{3})` part captures the first 3 digits while the `(.*)` captures the rest.
You can then access each part with `$1` to get the first captured group and `$2` to get the second captured group.

I'm certain that there are way better solutions, but that a starting point.

Comment: You might also only use group 1 `^(\d{3})` and replace with `'$1.`

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but @guijob has solution which suits me the best.

Answer (score 2):

This expression,

```
(?<=^[0-9]{3})
```

with a replacement of `.` might also work.

```js
const regex = /(?<=^[0-9]{3})/g;
const str = `9876544`;
const subst = `.`;

const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log(result);
```

The expression is explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Yf30Al/1/), if you wish to explore/simplify/modify it, and in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/Yf30Al/1/debugger), you can watch how it would match against some sample inputs, if you like.

Comment: The code snippet fails to run. JS does not support all of the lookarounds which server-side PCRE does.

Comment: Just figured you should know since OP is asking a JS question.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but @guijob has solution which suits me the best.